# SolrNet query assistance and some debugging options

Tags: solrnet

How would I use SolrNet to execute a GREATER THAN/LESS THAN query?

Example:

My documents have a field called "minimumDays" and I only want to return docs where that field is LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO the number I pass into the query.

I currently have this, but am not sure it's correct.

```
int requestedDays = 3;
var minimumNightsQuery = new SolrQueryByRange<int>("minimumDays", 0, requestedDays, true);
```

Am I on the right track?

The second part here is if there is some way to better understand the query that is being passed into Solr from SolrNet?  Debugging value or something where I can inspect the "q" variable for instance.

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SolrQueryByRange for the first part of your question.  Your code does look good.  debugging your query and results might help.  I have found that SolrNet does some odd things. - http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Facets#Arbitrary_facet_queries

For the second part, You can intercept the ISolrConnection and put in your own in between.  For a good start check this out: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/source/browse/trunk/SampleSolrApp/LoggingConnection.cs?r=513
I have one that logs the query and the results, and if a config setting is on it appends the debug param and logs that result also.  Its great info to have.... and one of the only ways to get it.

Comment: "I have found that SolrNet does some odd things" -> what odd things?

Comment: You can see the query that is being passed to Solr from the logs for the container that you are hosting Solr in as well. E.g. If you are running Solr in Tomcat, you can look at the catalina log files to see the actual http request that is being sent to Solr, which will include all of the parameters.

Comment: Yes, but it will not show the response, nor can you get the debug info.  So if you only need the query, then that is correct, it can be found in the logs if your logging level is correct and the query was not a POST.  Because most of my apps have large queries, I generally do a POST.